# Laravel: How to get duplicated records and group them together?

Tags: laravel, performance, laravel-5, eloquent

The code below is what I have to get all the duplicated products (by title) and group them together. It works perfectly fine. However, I so many records in my Products table and getting all of them causes a performance issue. Is there a way this could be optimised to avoid getting all records and group them in one query? Thank you.

```
$products = Product::all();

$groupsOfProducts = $products->groupBy('title');

$duplicatedProductsGrouped = [];

foreach($groupsOfProducts as $productGroup) {

    $productIsDuplicated = $productGroup->count() > 1; 

    if($productIsDuplicated) {

        $duplicatedProductsGrouped[] = $productGroup;

    }

}

var_dump($duplicatedProductsGrouped);
```

Comment: take out $products = Product::all();, you don't need it

Comment: `groupBy` will take the first row of a group. so just `groupBy` is fine. you don't need to do it the way you are doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `having` in the group by:

```
Product::groupBy('title')->having(DB::raw('count(*)'), ">", "1")->select('title')->get()
```

And you will get the titles of the duplicates, then you can query the database with those titles

EDIT:
Please also try and see if this is faster

```
Product::getQuery()->whereIn('title', array_column( DB::select('select title from products group by title having count(*) > 1'), 'title'))->get();
```

with this line you will get ONLY the products that has a duplicate title, and so your Collection groupby should be faster to aggregate the records by the `title`

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 2):

Let your database do the work. When you call `Product::all()`, you're getting every single record, then making PHP do the rest. Change your query to something like the following:

```
Product::selectRaw("title, COUNT(*) AS count")->groupBy("title")->get();
```

The result will be a `Collection` of `Product` instances with a `title` and `count` attribute, which you can access and determine duplicated ones:

```
$products = Product::selectRaw("title, COUNT(*) AS count")->groupBy("title")->get();
$duplicatedProducts = collect([]);
foreach($products AS $product){
  if($product->count > 1){
    $duplicatedProducts->push($product);
  }
}
dd($duplicatedProducts);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's really helpful. I would have upvoted this but I don't have enough points yet. I will come back to it when I do, thank you.